# TypeError: this.AjaxPoller is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript code that is responsible for sending ajax requests and update the DOM:

```
this.AjaxPoller = {
  poll: poll,
  request: request
};

function request() {
  $(".ajax_poller[data-url]").each(fetchDataForElement);
}

function fetchDataForElement(i, elem) {
  var url = $(elem).data("url");
  $.getJSON(url, handleJson);
}

function handleJson(data) {
  if (checkProgress(data)) {
    location.reload();
  };
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $(key+ ' .progress_info').html(val);
    $(key + ' .progress-bar').width(val);
  });
}

function poll() {
  setTimeout(this.AjaxPoller.request, 5000);
}

function checkProgress(obj) {
  var correct = true;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] != '100%') correct = false;
  }
  return correct;
}
```

When using this code, this function returns the error that I write in the title:

```
function poll() {
  setTimeout(this.AjaxPoller.request, 5000);
}
```

How can I change this code to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of try this.

```
var AjaxPoller = {
  poll: poll,
  request: request
};

function poll() {
  setTimeout(AjaxPoller.request, 5000);
}
```

As In case of

```
function poll() {
  setTimeout(this.AjaxPoller.request, 5000);
}
```

this.AjaxPoller is undefined in this case as **this** keywork refer to a function poll() and does not contain definition of AjaxPoller.

Comment: I must use this.request to make this code work in 100% because without this it sends only one ajax request instead of between 5 seconds. But I think this is a little smell because this may be referring to different context.